# PyInstaller app for Mac OS gives error upon opening

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```
Error message:"App" is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Bin
```

I have tried `sudo spctl --master-disable` to allow any app to be opened but with no luck. I have also tried creating a certificate from Keychain access and used:

```
codesign --force --deep --sign CertificateName /Users/myself/Desktop/myApp/dist/MyApp
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?